# Why can I see 2 different coordinates?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have the F3 screen open:

[image]

Why can I see 2 different coordinates? The X section of `XYZ:` section has a different coordinate to the X in `Looking at:` - even though I'm looking at the block I'm standing on.

Comment: What is -1.5 rounded down to the nearest integer (whole number)?

Comment: Ahh, because it's a negative. Now I get it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There are several different measurements shown here using different coordinate systems.

**XYZ** gives the *floating-point position* of your feet. This is where the game actually considers you to be.

**Block** gives the *integer coordinate* of the block that your feet occupy. This will always be within 1.0 of XYZ in each direction, but rounded up or down depending on your position relative to the center of the block.

**Facing** is the *direction* your face is pointing, in degrees around 2 axes. You could think of this as the latitude and longitude of your line of sight relative to the center of your head. In your case rotated almost 180 degrees down, and 90 degrees left. Note that this model follows the mathematical convention of degress counting counter-clockwise from +X rather than the geographic convention of clockwise from North.

**Looking at** is the *Block position* of the first non-air block that your line of sight intersects (ie, the block that your reticle appears on). Since you're looking almost straight down, it's the block beneath your feet. And since that's a solid block, your feet are on top of it - or +1 Y relative to its block coordinates.

Answer (score 4):

To address the question asked, what is the variance between XYZ and Looking At when you are looking at your feet you need to be aware that your position is not where you are standing.

XYZ is where you are considered to be but it is measured at your head/neck area. You can test this out by holding the shift key and letting it go with out moving, the Y value will vary.

Looking at is literally the block you are looking at. In this case it is the block under your feet so the Y value has decreased because again, the XYZ value is near your head, not your feet.

This is why people can perfectly light up an area according to the F3 screen and still get things to spawn because its the light level at your head, not your feet. Depending on if the light is coming from above or below it can be one level lower at your feet and thus a valid spawn location.

Comment: I'm asking about the difference in X, I'll edit to make it clearer.

Comment: @Tim This actually includes all of the rounding issues you are seeing. The 'Looking At' value is the block coordinates which are always their corner. You are standing in the middle of the block, or close enough as well as being over it. What I too find odd is that I would have expected the value to round down, not up as it has for the Looking At values. Guess I learned something new as well :) I can edit the answer if you would like that in there more explicitly.

Comment: It rounded that way because it's negative - so technically it has rounded "down" - which makes the number look "bigger".

Answer (score 0):

The `Looking at` is rounded down.

Rather than using `XYZ` (which is not rounded down) you should instead use the line beneath it called `Block`. This is rounded down in the same way`looking at` is.

Answer (score -1):

Your coordinates are not the block you're standing on, they're the exact position your feet are in.  Also, there's not just two, there's also Block, which is XYZ rounded down.

Comment: That's what I'm talking about, the Xs are different in the two.